# System.out slow in JBoss

Tags: jboss7.x, system.out

I'm implementing a project using JBoss 7.1.1 where I need to perform a System.out with 1.5mb text size but it's taking more than 6 seconds to perform the task, do you know if it is a normal behavior take so long?

Comment: It is not normal practice to write to System.out from inside a JEE container such as JBoss. I assume your intention is to write some diagnostics text? JBoss logging (e.g. log4j) may perform a better.

Comment: I tried to use the logback framework and the result was the same, trying to solve the problem, I found that the system.out from the ConsoleAppender was causing it. I already tested with other Applications Servers ( Ex: WebSphere Application Server ) and the results are 10x faster.

Comment: `System.out` is wrapped and sent sent to the logging already. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The intention of my colleague is to make a console log of a large string using Logback. Since internally Logback uses System.out the problem occurs only in JBoss. On Websphere Application Server the console log is done instantaneously